# Camel, Amazon SQS - No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I am currently working on a Spring Application using Camel which is going to poll SQS as an entry point into the application (1st route).
I am successfully able to Achieve this using Spring's XML based Approach.

My AmazonSQSClient Bean:

```
<bean id="sqsClient" class="com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient">
    <constructor-arg ref="sqsCredentialsProvider" />
    <property name="endpoint" value="${aws.sqs.endpoint}" />
</bean>
```

My Camel Route:

```
<route id="pollMessages">
    <from id="sqsEndpoint" uri="aws-sqs://{{queue.name}}?amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient&amp;deleteAfterRead=false" />
    <to uri="direct:readSQSMessage" />
</route>
```

Everything works as I want at this point with the above approach.

Now I am trying to migrate all my beans and Camel Configuration to Java Based Approach.

I have created my Amazon SQS Client Bean as following:

```
@Bean
public AmazonSQS sqsClient(){
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    AmazonSQSClient client = new AmazonSQSClient(sqsCredentialsProvider(), clientConfiguration);
    client.setEndpoint(sqsEndpoint);

    return client;
}
```

And, I am creating Camel route (snippet) looks like:

```
@Bean
public CamelContext camelContext() throws Exception{
    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

    camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {

            from("aws-sqs://"+fulfillmentQueueName+"?amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient&amp;delay="+fulfillmentQueuePollInterval)
            .to("direct:parseSQSMessage");

            }
    });

    camelContext.start();
    return camelContext;
}
```

However, I am getting errors using this approach:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: amazonSQSClient as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS with value #sqsClient

I read [here](http://camel.apache.org/aws-sqs.html#JMS-style%20Selectors) how to construct a Java style Camel Route

I read [here](http://camel.apache.org/aws-sqs.html#Advanced%20AmazonSQS%20configuration) that I need to bind the AWS Client to Registry (registry.bind) but I am not able to find a bind method on any Registry except JNDI

I tried this as well:

```
SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
registry.put("sqsClient", sqsClient());

CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
```

But got same error.

I searched a lot and tried reading up, plan to keep doing more but am unable to find any complete example doing what I need to do. Snippets are helping much here.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For the `amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient` parameter Camel try to find an entry in the Registry (ApplicationContextRegistry) where the key is `sqsClient`.

In your first solution (where you specified the bean in xml) you set the `id` of the bean and Camel registered the bean with `id=sqsClient` in the ApplicationContextRegistry. But when you configured the bean in code you haven't set the id/name of it, so Camel didn't find it. To make it work you have to set the name of the Bean!

Solution:

```
@Bean(name = "sqsClient")
public AmazonSQS sqsClient(){
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    AmazonSQSClient client = new AmazonSQSClient(sqsCredentialsProvider(), clientConfiguration);
    client.setEndpoint(sqsEndpoint);
    return client;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `SpringCamelContext` (it takes spring's `ApplicationContext` as a contructor parameter) - it will look up your sqs client by bean name "sqsClient" in the application context.

if you're using spring boot and camel-spring then `SpringCamelContext` will be created by default.